# SQL for MSACCESS how to implement character delimited data hierarchy?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, data-structures

Say, there's a flattened **sequential** hierarchy table with a special character "+" denoting hierarchy level

```
hr_table
ID   FIELD1        My irrelevant comments
----------------
1    ASSETS        No pluses - it means level0 hierarchy
2    +ASSETS_01    Level1 hierarchy
3    ++345667654   Level2 hierarchy
4    ++563255512   Level2 hierarchy
5    ...
```

Is there a way to create field structure in MSACCESS using SQL? I am trying to structure final data as follows:

```
final_data_table
ID  LEVEL0     LEVEL1       LEVEL2    ...
-------------------------------------------
1   ASSETS     ASSETS_01    345667654
2   ASSETS     ASSETS_01    563255512
```

Any/all help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many levels can there be, and will there always be rows for the maximum of levels (i.e. if 3 levels, will there always be 3 rows to populate your table)? I know you could handle in Access using VBA, and Excel could be used to reformat to flat rows.

Comment: What criteria determines those Level2 numbers go with ASSETS_01 and not ASSETS_02?

Comment: FIELD1 members would need to be examined to count MAX occurrence of "+". That would determine the maximum number of levels. But that is pretty much pre-determined. Say, the maximum number of levels is 5 (as an example) and it would not change.

Comment: Because "++345667654" sequentially followed higher hierarchy member "+ASSETS_01"...had it occurred later in the table, following a hypothetical member "+ASSETS_02" then the proper LEVEL1 hierarchy would have been ASSETS_02. Basically, sequential integrity links "child" to the most recently listed LEVEL hierarchy descriptor...

Comment: I suspected as much. Then I agree with @WayneG.Dunn, use VBA loop structure to read recordset object and write records to a 'temp' table (table is permanent, records are temporary). And this presumes ID value will always be increasing and can be depended on to correctly sort records.

Answer (score 0):

Curiosity got the better of me so I explored query approach. I resorted to using domain aggregate functions. Be aware domain aggregate functions can perform slowly with large datasets. However, consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT hr_table.ID, IIf([Field1] Like "+*",Left([Field1],InStrRev([Field1],"+")),0) AS Prefix, IIf([Field1] Like "+*",Null,[Field1]) AS Asset1, IIf(InStrRev([Field1],"+")=1,Mid([Field1],2),Null) AS Asset2, IIf([Field1] Like "++*",Mid([Field1],InStrRev([Field1],"+")+1),Null) AS Data
FROM hr_table;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Query1.ID, Query1.Prefix, DMax("Asset1","Query1","ID<=" & [ID]) AS A1, DMax("Asset2","Query1","ID<=" & [ID]) AS A2, Query1.Data
FROM Query1
WHERE ((Not (Query1.Data) Is Null));
```

Query3:

```
SELECT Query2.Prefix, Query2.A1, Query2.A2, Query2.Data, DCount("*","Query2","A1='" & [A1] & "' AND A2='" & [A2] & "' AND Prefix = '" & [Prefix] & "' AND ID<=" & [ID]) AS GrpSeq
FROM Query2;
```

Query4:

```
TRANSFORM Max(Query3.Data) AS MaxOfData
SELECT Query3.A1, Query3.A2, Query3.GrpSeq
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.A1, Query3.A2, Query3.GrpSeq
PIVOT Query3.Prefix;
```

I am definitely not sure about treatment of Level3 and beyond. Could be VBA will be only way to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The following code has been tested and works with the data structure you have mentioned. It is currently set to handle up to 10 levels, but that can be easily changed. The tricky part was to NOT write out the record until you have all levels for that ONE row (New row starts with different level1 value, or when more than one level-n value provided). The final row is written after eof of input.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function Parse_Fields()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsIN    As DAO.recordSet
Dim rsOUT   As DAO.recordSet
Dim i       As Integer
Dim iPlus   As Integer
Dim aLevels(10)
Dim bAdding As Boolean

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rsIN = dbs.OpenRecordset("hr_table")
    Set rsOUT = dbs.OpenRecordset("final_data_table")
    bAdding = False

    Do While Not rsIN.EOF
        'Debug.Print "Input: " & rsIN!field1
        If left(rsIN!field1, 1) <> "+" Then
            ' Check if not first time thru... if not, write prior levels..
            If bAdding = True Then
                rsOUT.Update
            End If
            iPlus = 0
            rsOUT.AddNew
            rsOUT!Level0 = rsIN!field1
            bAdding = True
            ' Don't issue the .Update yet! Wait until another Level0 or EOF.
        Else
            For iPlus = 1 To 10         ' Change code if more than ten levels
                If Mid(rsIN!field1, iPlus, 1) <> "+" Then Exit For
            Next iPlus

            ' Check if same level as previous!  If so, do NOT overlay!
            If Not IsNull(rsOUT.Fields(iPlus)) Then
                For i = 1 To iPlus - 1      ' Save the proper levels for the new record.
                    aLevels(i) = rsOUT.Fields(i)
                Next i
                rsOUT.Update                ' Need to write out record.
                rsOUT.AddNew
                For i = 1 To iPlus          ' Populate the new record with prior levels
                     rsOUT.Fields(i) = aLevels(i)
                Next i
                rsOUT.Fields(iPlus) = Mid(rsIN!field1, iPlus)       ' Add the new level
            Else
                rsOUT.Fields(iPlus) = Mid(rsIN!field1, iPlus)
            End If
        End If
        rsIN.MoveNext               ' Get next input
    Loop

    ' Need to write out the final record we have beenbuilding!
    rsOUT.Update

    rsIN.Close
    rsOUT.Close
    Set rsIN = Nothing
    Set rsOUT = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Debug.Print "FINISHED!!"

End Function
```